# Cleaner leaving defamatory messages on fridge - is this a crime?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales

Come across a situation with a friend of mine which I'm not sure is actually illegal or just really bad practice, they live in university accommodation and while all residents are out one of the staff/cleaners arranged fridge magnets into offensive messages about the residents, due to prior tension this triggered an altercation between them, has the cleaner broken a law or is this just bad practice?

Comment: I can't think of any reason this would be illegal, but it's very unprofessional. I bet the cleaning company would be interested to hear how their cleaning staff are behaving..

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Defamatory and offensive are not the same

“He is a child molester” is defamatory and illegal (unless he is, of course).

“She is a two-faced f___ing b___h with the morals of an alley cat and the integrity of a politician” is offensive and legal.

Neither is a crime.

Answer (score 2):

Being "illegal" does not mean that it is a crime. It is possibly illegal, but not necessarily a crime. It could be breach of contract or defamation, neither of which are legal. The former case might not even involve the courts, and in the latter case would involve a lawsuit but not prosecution.
It might be a crime under law outlawing hate speech, [Public Order Act 1986 §18](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/part/III) or especially [§4a](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/part/I)
which forbids a person

> with intent to cause a person harassment, alarm or distress...
>   displays any writing, sign or other visible representation which is
>   threatening, abusive or insulting, thereby causing that or another
>   person harassment, alarm or distress.

The content of the message would matter.